# Anorm save integer and string values to table

Tags: postgresql, anorm

I have the following block of code, created to insert a response to a question for a survey:

```
 def saveResponse(qId:String,userEmail:String, response:String) = {
  DB.withConnection{
    implicit c =>
      val notAString = qId.toInt
      val id = SQL(s"INSERT INTO responses(response,useremail,questionid) values ({userResp},{eMail},{quesId})")
        .on('userResp -> s"$response", 'eMail -> s"$userEmail",'quesId -> s"$notAString")
        .executeInsert()
```

When i run this code, i get the following error:

```
[PSQLException: ERROR: column "questionid" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying  
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I have tried several different ways of casting (valueOf, toInt, etc) keep getting the same error. I played with different resultSetParsers but am not entirely sure how to use these as the documentation seems a bit sparse. When i enter this query in to the psql console by itself it seems to work without any issues, like such:

`insert into responses(response,useremail,questionid) values ('true','qbert@bacon.com',2);`

i am unsure what i am doing wrong with my anorm code and why i am unable to process strings and ints in the same insert block. when i removed the int part it does insert just the email and question response, but this is quite useless as i have no question ID to reference it to then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
'quesId -> s"$notAString"
```

needs to be:

```
'quesId -> notAString
```

for it to be passed as an integer.

Comment: yeah pretty annoyed i spent this much time not realizing that. quite simple

Comment: Using plain string interpolation to prepare SQL statement is not good. Better to use Anorm SQL interpolation: `SQL"INSERT INTO responses(response,useremail,questionid) values ($response, $userEmail, $notAString)"`

Comment: That's cleaner, still some way from being as good as a Scala-friendly framework like Slick - at least until Slick gets as clever as SQL experts. :)